# ProgressDialog size doen't change after removing text

Tags: android, size, progressdialog

I'm using undetermined ProgressDialog with text 'Loading...' and other similar texts.
I decided to remove texts and leave plain progres indicator.
Unexpectedly sizde of indicator remain big enought to contain text inside.
How to remove it?

### Update:

```
m_progressBar = new ProgressDialog(LoginForm.this);
m_progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
m_progressBar.setCancelable(true);
m_progressBar.setProgressStyle(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately only custom progress solves this.
There are a lot of samples here in stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your xml

`<ProgressBar 
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom ProgressBar google it there are a lot of example of creating custom `ProgressBar`. you cant do with android own `ProgressBar`